# Limited Subscription - API Manager

Tags: subscription, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm running WSO2 API Manager 1.6. Is it possible to limit the subscrition for special set of users?
So that specified users will only have access to mentioned APIs

EX:

```
APIs  : API1,API2,API3,API4,API5
Users : User1,User2,User3

User1 -> API1, API2
User2 -> API3, API4
User3 -> API1, API5
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the access by roles. When publishing APIs select particular roles in Visibility option. So, users assigned with that roles will have access for that APIs.

Comment: +1 for the answer. What I exactly want it APIs should be shown to the public but only specific set of registered users should be able to subscriber for a particular API? How can I do it?

Comment: You can use subscription option?

Comment: The problem is that, once I create an account for the user he can subscriber to anything he likes. That's exactly what I want to limit.

Answer (score 0):

API Creator and API Publisher roles can view all APIs in their tenant store, whilst anonymous users will only be able to view APIs of which visibility is set to "Public". Setting Subscription Visibility to "Available to Specific Tenants" should resolve your problem. For further clarifications, please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-APIvisibilityandsubscription.

Comment: I want to set all APIs to public but allow particular users to be subscribe red as mentioned in the question above.